# Update database record by selected id and reset the initial record

Tags: mysql, sql

Please how do i update all record to `0` and set only the selected ID to `1`

```
UPDATE address SET default_addr = 1 
WHERE addr_id = 100 AND user = 'peter'
```

The above query will update the selected address to 1 which is good, but i want to set other address or the old selected default to 0 with one query

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Do you want only one `default_addr` set to "1" in the entire table?  That is what your question suggests.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes i want only one `default_addr` to set to 1 and other once will return to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
UPDATE address
    SET default_addr = (addr_id = 100 AND user = 'peter');
```

(This shorthand uses the fact that MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with "0" for false and "1" for true.)

If you want only one default address for the user named Peter, then use a `where`:

```
UPDATE address
    SET default_addr = (addr_id = 100)
    WHERE user = 'peter';
```

I suspect this is the logic that you really want.

Comment: smart using boolean

Answer (score 1):

use a conditional update using `case` statement

```
update address set default_address = case when addr_id = 100 and user = 'peter' then 1 else 0 end
```

[here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/PTGC833010)

I built a sample schema. These are often helpful to provide in your future questions.